# Make phone running Android 2.3.3 re-download configuration settings from ISP

Tags: 2.3-gingerbread, connection-issues, mobile-network, mobile-data, apn

When I first inserted my SIM into my phone, it prompted to download configuration settings for things such as Data, MMS etc... It worked fine for about a year but I have started having problems such as:

1. After putting phone on flight mode and off, switch data on and off etc..., after scanning for and meddling with Mobile Networks, I managed to make it temporarily work with 2G, but then it automatically switched to 3G, even when having Manual Network Selection on. I also realized that a prefix has now appeared before the original network name.

Is there anyway to re-download these files (preferably the newest versions) without having to fully format my Android? I really appreciate any help ASAP as I am a little stuck without a constant connection.

Thanks.

PS: My provider is SRI Etisalat.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this page](http://www.etisalat.lk/vas/gprs-and-mms/gprs/) you can obtain your provider settings by sending an SMS with just the word "Five" to 2211. Most providers have a number you can send text messages to in order to receive the settings again.

If that fails, you can try to manually configure your access point to use the following data (taken from [this page](http://mobilebroadband.gishan.net/entry/37/etisalat-gprs-settings-for-android-375g)):
Navigate to **Settings** > **Wireless & networks** > **Mobile networks** > **Access point names**, then press the menu button and select "New APN". Then enter:

```
Name:      Etisalat
APN:       wap
Proxy:     *not set*
Port:      *not set*
Username:  *not set*
Password:  *not set*
Server:    *not set*
MMSC:      *not set*
MMS Proxy: *not set*
MMS Port:  *not set*
MCC:       413
MNC:       03
Authentication type: None
APN type:  default,supl
APN protocol: IPv4
```

Then press the menu button and select save.

If that doesn't work either, you can find a lot of alternate configurations on [this page](http://wiki.melberi.com/2013/05/etisalat-sri-lanka-internet-apn.html).

Comment: Thanks, but "Five" doesn't work. Also, apn is EBB, which at the moment is not working and I am using "INTERNET" as the APN.

Comment: Have you tried deleting the exisiting APN settings and adding these APN settings manually?